# "did little to raise the tone"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

> Still, the scandal was there, and during the months that followed Arendt's critics seized on it as evidence that she was intellectually untrustworthy. Her defenders, who have made her into an object of passionate hagiography in recent years, were not slow to respond but **did little to raise the tone**.  ([source](http://www.nytimes.com/2002/01/06/books/chapters/06-1st-lilla.html?pagewanted=all))

What does exactly "did little to raise the tone" in the context of the above excerpt? I lean towards the interpretation that the defenders of Arendt reacted in more defensive way than her critics and that their voice was not so audible but I am not sure.

Comment: You shouldn't begin your quotation with a sentence that refers to a prior one.

Comment: I believe the "tone" being referred to is Ettinger's reading of an "incomplete correspondence" mentioned in the previous paragraph: "Whether Arendt did this out of a deep psychological need for affection from a father figure, out of Jewish self-hatred, or out of a foolish wish to ingratiate herself with a charlatan she mistook for a genius, Ettinger could not decide. So she advanced all three hypotheses, on the basis of her private reading of an incomplete correspondence."

Comment: That is, it's not as much a matter of civility (as "raise the tone" might otherwise imply) as intellectual thoroughness and the avoidance of sensationalism.

Comment: @TRomano- If you edited your last two comments into an answer, I would up-vote it. Well said.

Comment: The choice of words is puzzling. "Did little" seems to suggest that they were expected to do more. But that does not seem to match the rest of the text.

Answer (score 1):

The **tone** in a discussion is the general **feeling**, **mood**, or **attitude** of the discussion.  Just as it is an analogy to a **musical tone**, **tone** can be **raised** and **lowered**.

**Raising the tone** of a discussion or argument is **to increase** or **heighten** the **intensity** or **intellectual rigour** and thereby **raising** the standard of discussion.

**Setting the tone** establishes the **feeling** or **mood** of an event or happening.

> His opening remarks **set the tone** for the rest of the discussion.

whereas

> Her superfluous remarks **lowered the tone** of the discussion.

or

> The experience and real-world examples **raised the tone** of the discussion.

I believe the **tone** referred to in the NYT article was **the debate** on the **intellectual rigour and character of Arendt in general** and possibly Arendt's **defence of Heidegger's actions as a Nazi sympathizer in particular**, just after Ettinger's publication..

After Ettinger's publication, Arendt's critics

> **seized** on it as evidence that she was intellectually untrustworthy

possibly because of the close relationship she had with Heidegger, her critics may have felt she was **compromised** by love.  Arendt's defenders

> **were not slow to respond**

**in defence** of Arendt (whom they thought of in a saintly way), meaning they defended her as well as they could, but

> did little to **raise the tone**

left implicit is the **argument of Arendt's credibility**.  I believe Arendt's **critics** resorted to something similar to **tabloid sensationalism** in attacking her character and Arendt's **defenders** were **not able to respond** since only a handful of people had actually seen the letters.

Once the letters were generally published

> *it* **more than set the record straight**

showing the intellectual strength of Arendt, Heidegger, and Jaspers relationship, regardless of their personal intertwining.

[ BTW: Interesting article, thanks ]